# Django admin actions update foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this simple action I added in my admin.py file.

```
def groupA(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(group=1)
groupA.short_description = "Group A"

//
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
actions = [groupA]
```

So far everything works as expected.

The problem is that group is a foreign key and it would be more manageable if I could do something like

```
def groupA(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(group="A")
groupA.short_description = "Group A"
```

I tried with the queryset below but no luck.

```
     queryset.update(group__name="A")
```

My group model looks like something like that :

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='', blank=True)
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So is it possible to do admin actions with the **str** representation of my Group model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you import the group model, get the Group A and update all like this?

```
def groupA(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    from models import Group
    g = Group.objects.get(name="Group A")
    queryset.update(group=g)
```

Comment: It worked! Lets say I have like 20 groups, is there an elegant way to populate the actions another way than defining 20 functions ?

Comment: I think there is some way to do that, but I am not sure :(

Comment: I found a sniplet, works like a charm ! https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1836/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and noticed @metraon actually found a nice snippet but it's only in the comments. The snippet worked like a charm for me, even though it's 7 years later now, so I wanted to make it easier to find by posting it as an answer.

Here is the snippet, found at https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1836/ by metraon:

```
def create_action(quality):
    def action(modeladmin, request, queryset): queryset.update(quality=quality)
    name = "mark_%s" % (quality,)
    return (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % (quality,)))

class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'quality')
            
    def get_actions(self, request):
        return dict(create_action(q) for q in models.Quality.objects.all())
```

Comment: I appreciate that it works, but there is so much voodoo here :-)